# JavaScript add multiple function to event at runtime

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to add a function to `OnChange` event of textbox at runtime (on page load). But if there is already a function define at `onchange` event of the particular textbox then I need to make sure the both function get a call at `onchang`e event. How can I achieve that?
I am using IE7.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the addEventListener function on that textbox

```
  var tb = document.getElementById("textbox");
  tb.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    alert(tb.value);
  }, false);
```

But for older versions of IE (IE6), this will not work. For that you can use the [addEvent](http://ejohn.org/blog/flexible-javascript-events/)

Comment: addEventListener has a third argument which is only optional in recent browser (since FF 6). You should provide that parameter for broadest compatibility.
That argument determines whether to capture (true) the event or to let it propagate upward (false).
Check out the function reference at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener